# Is "The Man in the High Castle" finished?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle, philip-k-dick

I just started reading it so please don't spoil!
I just wanna know if the book and/or its story is finished. I have presumed it's finished because it was first published back in the 1960's, but I have come across some reviews that indicate the book is not finished, also the wiki page says that the author was trying to write a sequel but eventually didn't. So before seriously driving into the book, I would like to know if the book is finished or not. By "finished" my bottom line is that I don't want to experience an unsettled feeling after reading the book.

Comment: I have [an answer on another SE site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108943/31394) about this. I was about to post it here, but you seem to have included most of that information in your question. Would that satisfy you as an answer, or are you looking for something more? Also, if you want an answer to demonstrate based on book content rather than author commentary, how do you expect it to do so while avoiding spoilers? :-)

Comment: `lacks a resolution`, that is good enough for me... Maybe I should drop reading it, I don't like books without a complete resolution.

Comment: But won’t you equally experience a lack of resolution by not finishing reading it? Perhaps it’s too late for you to avoid lack of authorial resolution, you were lost the moment you began... perhaps your best hope is to press on and learn all you can about the story to equip yourself to find your own, speculative, resolution!

Comment: It seems difficult to imagine a definitive resolution to *The Man in the High Castle*. It would have been a travesty for Dick to bring about an end to the Nazi regime. Maybe you could have Frink escape to the Neutral Zone, but would he really be any safer there from the Nazis than in Japan-controlled San Francisco? Various things that happen in the book suggest not. So the current ending, where he evades all the immediate threats and keeps on with his life, might be as much of a resolution as you could possibly hope for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borrowing from [my answer on another SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108943/31394) ... the novel ends with

> Nobusuke Tagomi coming back to his own timeline, ordering Frank Frink released, then having a heart attack.

However, it also lacks a complete resolution: Philip K Dick always planned to go back to it and write a sequel some day. From [this interview](http://www.philipkdickfans.com/literary-criticism/interviews/hour-25-a-talk-with-philip-k-dick/) with the author (emphasis mine):

> But then when it came time to close down the novel the I Ching had no more to say. And so **there’s no real ending on it. I like to regard it as an open ending.** It will segue into a sequel sometime.
>
> [...]
>
> And that’s why I’ve never written a sequel to it. Because it’s too horrible. It’s too awful. **I started several times to write a sequel to it** and I would had to go back and read about Nazis again. And I’d just like to off every one of them, it’s what I’d like to do. And so I could never do a sequel to it. Somebody would have to come in and help me do a sequel to it.